# Unity C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on line 64 and I can't figure out what I need to do

Everything is working like the lives are showing up and the timer and the score is but the score isn't increasing if you can tell me what is wrong I would be so thankful

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

private CountdownTimer myTimer;

private int score = 0;
private int lives = 3;
private int DEATH_Y = -10;

public Texture2D LivesLeft1;
public Texture2D LivesLeft2;
public Texture2D LivesLeft3;

public int GetScore(){
    return score;
}

public int GetLives()
{
    return lives;
}

private void Start()
{
    myTimer = GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();
}

private void Update()
{
    float y = transform.position.y;

    if (y < DEATH_Y) {
        MoveToStartPosition();
        lives--;
    }

    if (score == 10)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Level2");
    }

    if (lives == 0)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
    }

}

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
    DisplayLives();

    int secondsLeft = myTimer.GetSecondsRemaining();//this is line 64
    string timeMessage = "Seconds left = " + secondsLeft;
    GUILayout.Label(timeMessage);

    string scoreMessage = "Score = " + score;
    GUILayout.Label (scoreMessage);
}

private void DisplayLives()
{
    int playerLives = GetLives();

    if (1 == playerLives) {
        GUILayout.Label(LivesLeft1);
    }

    if (2 == playerLives) 
    {
        GUILayout.Label(LivesLeft2);
    }

    if(3 == playerLives){
        GUILayout.Label(LivesLeft3);
    }
}

private void MoveToStartPosition()
{
    Vector3 startPosition = new Vector3(0,5,0);
    transform.position = startPosition;
}

/**
 * what increases the score
 * anything with the tag Hidden
*/
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    string tag = c.tag;

    if("Hidden" == tag)
    {
        score++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably `OnGUI()` is called before `Start()`?

Comment: Could you point out where line 64 is? According to the editor I just copied this into, its `private void DisplayLives()` which can't have that exception...

Comment: This is line 64 according to MonoDeveloper `int secondsLeft = myTimer.GetSecondsRemaining();`

Comment: That says `myTimer` is null. Your `OnGUI()` is definitely being called before `Start()` or `GetComponent<CountdownTimer>()` is returning null. Perhaps some breakpoints in those general areas and single stepping the application would help you to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your GameObject have the Component called CountdownTimer?
Also, change the Start function to Awake, because that line is not depending on anything else.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that wasn't added for some reason but now there    is something overlapping the time now and I can't read what it says but I think it's the timer and score overlapping again is there something that I need to change?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping? Your GUI position boxes?

Comment: Yeah it's like it's writing it twice on top of each other now

Comment: Ok, but then figure out why they position the way they do. Experiment with it.

Comment: Looking closer at it it looks like it's counting down and counting up so the timer is increasing and also decreasing at the same time on top of each other